# CSV writer adds the first line to the last cell

Tags: python, excel, csv, export-to-csv

I am trying to write to a csv file that has been saved with another program (excel and others).
However when I open the file to write to it, the first line written is added to last cell of the last line.

```
file.csv
['1','2','3']
['1','2','3']
```

```
import csv   
fields=['A','B','C']
with open('file.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(fields)
```

Expected results:

```
['1','2','3']
['1','2','3']
['A','B','C']
```

Actual results:

```
['1','2','3']
['1','2','3A','B','C']
```

If I just write to file then write to it again without viewing it, there's no issue, but if I open the file, and save it inside the program the next line written is added to the previous line instead of becoming it's own line.

I assume there is a formatting issue with how the program saves the file, but I am at a loss as to how to fix it.

Comment: Why are u using the `newline=''` argument?

Comment: @Serial Lazer I added it when trying to figure out what the issue was and they used it in some of the examples. the problem remains without it

Comment: @SerialLazer - the [writer documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) tells you to use `newline=""`. The reason is that the writer will write "\r\n" conforming to specification and doesn't want python's newline conversions in there also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lines in CSV files should always be terminated with a "\r\n" sequence, even if its the last line in the file. In the grand tradition of CSV programming, this is often ignored. The fix is to write a program that peeks at the file and fixes it as needed before use. And write a bug against the "other" program that wrote the nonconforming CSV in the first place.

```
import csv

def csv_delimiter_fixer(filename):
    with open(filename, 'a+b') as fileobj:
        fileobj.seek(-1, 2)
        if fileobj.read(1) != b"\n":
            fileobj.write(b"\r\n")

fields=['A','B','C']
filename = 'file.csv'
csv_delimiter_fixer(filename)
with open('file.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(fields)
```

Comment: using that same logic could I also open the file, read it into a list, then write that list over the old file before I start adding additional lines. Effectively creating a fresh correctly formatted file? I am already reading the list first to not add duplicate lines.

Comment: At what point am I using too much much memory just moving the same info around? Would it be too much to write the entire file every instance?

Comment: That's a good question. It will depend on expected size. You need to read the file any way to avoid duplicates. On a normal PC a few 10's of megs of data isn't that bad. If the data is getting really large, you may need a different scheme. That depends on the data. If its a bunch of numbers, using numpy or pandas and some other file save format may be better. Maybe this is the type of data that should be put in a database for more efficient query later. What to to depends on several factors.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The largest file I've created got to 10MB, I may integrate a database at a later date. I have been using pandas for my other programs, but It seemed a little overkill for a little web scraper I run overnight.

Comment: You could add a bit of logging to see if the time is too long but 10 meg isn't that bad, especially if the file is read multiple times and is in the operating system file cache.